# Creating an Objective-C equivalent Getter and Setter in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

What is the equivalent of the following Objective-C code in Swift?

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter = isOpen) BOOL open;
```

Specifically, how does one declare a variable in Swift to synthesize the getter with a custom name?

Furthermore, how can you subsequently override the implementation of the getter and setter?

Comment: I think you really need to read Apple's book on Swift. It's free!

Comment: @ColinE: answer to about 50% of questions in [tag:swift-language]

Comment: I would encourage close voters to read the discussion here. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason

Comment: “Use the @objc(<#name#>) attribute to provide Objective-C names for properties and methods when necessary. For example, you can mark a property called enabled to have a getter named isEnabled in Objective-C like this”

Comment: @ColinE for these sorts of basic questions StackOverflow is a better reference and tends to provide better search results rather than digging through an old-fashioned dead-tree style guide or manual.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your assumption was close, but a few things could be changed. I will try to help you get as close as possible to the Objective-C version.

First of all, the `nonatomic` and `assign` are irrelevant in swift. That leaves us with

```
@property (getter = isOpen) BOOL open;
```

Since properties in swift are just instance variables, the swift translation would be as follows.

```
var open:Bool
```

Although this has the same basic functionality as the Objective-C version, it is lacking the named getter (`isOpen`). Unfortunately, there is no direct translation to swift for this (yet). You could use a custom getter and setter.

```
var open:Bool {
    get {
        // custom getter
    }
    set {
        // custom setter
    }
}
```

A rather crude work around would be to make *another* function literally called `isOpen` that would act as a getter.

```
func isOpen() -> Bool { return self.open }
```

In conclusion, what you are asking is only slightly possible, but hopefully in later releases of swift can become a reality.

Comment: This will be much more prevalent once Swift gets access control mechanisms (they have been [promised by the Swift team](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/227288?start=0&tstart=0)).

Comment: A named getter is written: `var isOpen:Bool { get {} }` and if you want to also have a setter use `var isOpen:Bool { set {} get {} }` - whenever a value is set it is passed to the setter as `newValue` - note also that the property must have a type declared in both instances

Comment: I think this is a good answer for this basic question and encourage you to vote to reopen this question. I have clarified the question so it matches up better with the answer.

Answer (score 20):

```
var open: Bool {
    @objc(isOpen)
    get {
        // custom getter
    }
    set {
        // custom setter
    }
}
```

Leads to this generated header:

```c
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC11SwiftToObjC9TestClass")
@interface TestClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, getter=isOpen) BOOL open;
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

Comment: It's worth nothing that the same behavior can be achieved for the setter by moving the `@objc(<custom name>)` line to above the `set` line. Since it's a setter, it requires a parameter, so you'll also need a `:` after the setter name.

Comment: Not work for me :( , dose not appear in getter list when I try to get getter from swift class

        unsigned int propertyCount = 0;
        objc_property_t * properties = class_copyPropertyList([object class], &propertyCount);
        NSDictionary * info = [self getObjectInfoWithProperties:properties propertyCount:propertyCount];
        NSMutableArray * propertyGetters = [info objectForKey:@"propertyGetters"];

Answer (score -2):

As a remarq, for the setter you need to repeat the `@objc` directive:

```
@objc( setOpen:) set { self.open = newValue }
```

Don't forguet the semi-column.

A particular thing is that, doing this, `self.open` will call the setter/getter itself and produce an infinite loop.
In Obj-C you fix it using `self->open`. How do this if swift?