# Rename property getter in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In Objective-C we can give getters different name when declaring a property like this:

```
@property (getter=isEnabled) BOOL enabled;
```

Can something like this be done in Swift? I have a vague memory of reading something about it several months ago, but can't find anything now.

---

#### Update:

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24151441/1607485) is satisfactory. However I managed to find the source of my vague memory. It was in `Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C` book and it goes like this:

> Use the @objc(<#name#>) attribute to provide Objective-C names for
>   properties and methods when necessary. For example, you can mark a
>   property called enabled to have a getter named isEnabled in
>   Objective-C like this:
>
> ```
> var enabled: Bool {
>     @objc(isEnabled) get {
>         /* ... */
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Read the manual: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html