# How to conform to Objective-C protocol with readonly properties in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

We're currently using this library in our project... https://github.com/OliverLetterer/SLExpandableTableView

How would one go about conforming to the `UIExpandingTableViewCell` protocol in Swift?

Here is a copy...

```
typedef enum {
    UIExpansionStyleCollapsed = 0,
    UIExpansionStyleExpanded
} UIExpansionStyle;

@protocol UIExpandingTableViewCell <NSObject>

@property (nonatomic, assign, getter = isLoading) BOOL loading;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIExpansionStyle expansionStyle;
- (void)setExpansionStyle:(UIExpansionStyle)style animated:(BOOL)animated;

@end
```

I've tried the following but still says it doesn't conform to it...

```
class SectionHeaderCell: UITableViewCell, UIExpandingTableViewCell {

    @objc var loading: Bool
    @objc private(set) var expansionStyle: UIExpansionStyle

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setExpansionStyle(style: UIExpansionStyle, animated: Bool) {


    }
}
```

Is it because of the way UIExpansionStyle is defined without using NS_ENUM?

*confused*

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151197/getter-and-setter-variable-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short Answer

Use something in the spirit of:

```
var loading:Bool {
    @objc(isLoading) get {
        return self._isLoading
    }
    set(newValue){
        _isLoading = newValue
    }
}
```

---

## Long Answer

Create a new, fresh project, do a `pod init`, add a `Podfile` similar to the one below, and run `pod install`.

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
target 'SO-32254051' do
pod 'SLExpandableTableView'
end
```

## Using Objective-C Named Properties Attribute in Swift

As read in the [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/Migration.html) documentation:

> Use the @objc(<#name#>) attribute to provide Objective-C names for properties and methods when necessary.

The conforming issue is about just that: custom getter name.

## Complete Solution

**Adopt protocol**

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UIExpandingTableViewCell { ... }
```

**Define local storage**

```
var _isLoading:Bool = false
var _expansionStyle:UIExpansionStyle = UIExpansionStyle(0)
```

**Implement named getter and setters**

```
var loading:Bool {
    @objc(isLoading) get {
        return self._isLoading
    }
    set(newValue){
        _isLoading = newValue
    }
}

private(set) var expansionStyle:UIExpansionStyle {
    get{
        return _expansionStyle
    }
    set(newValue){
        _expansionStyle = newValue
    }
}

func setExpansionStyle(style: UIExpansionStyle, animated: Bool) {
    self.expansionStyle = style
    // ...
}
```

## Using Enum shorthand

You also mention *Is it because of the way UIExpansionStyle is defined without using NS_ENUM?* in your question. That is actually a different problem entirely, one you could easily fix in the library and do a `git push` and pull request for.

Since the `enum` is not defined as bellow, you cannot use the `.Collapsed` shorthand.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, UIExpansionStyle) {
    UIExpansionStyleCollapsed = 0,
    UIExpansionStyleExpanded
};
```

and subsequently do this in **Swift**:

```
var _expansionStyle:UIExpansionStyle = UIExpansionStyle.Collapsed
```

---

*Compiled, linked, built & ran.*