# Named Obj-C Property Getters and Setters in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I am looking for a general solution to access:

1. **Obj-C** named property getters and named property setters from **Swift**
2. Conform to an Objective-C `@protocol` with `readonly` properties

*Similar* to [Creating an Objective-C equivalent Getter and Setter in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151197/getter-and-setter-variable-in-swift), which is **closed**, yet does not offer a satisfying answer.

---

**Objective-C to Swift Properties Example:**

I have an Objective-C protocol defined with two problematic properties, one with a custom getter `isEnabled` and another with a private setter `exists`.

```
@protocol SomeProtocol <NSObject>
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter = isEnabled) BOOL enabled;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) BOOL exists;
@end
```

How can I access these Objective-C properties from Swift?

This does not seem to work:

```
func isEnabled() -> Bool { return self.enabled }
```

and neither does:

```
var isEnabled:Bool {
    get { }
    set { }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

---

Straight from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/Migration.html):

> Use the @objc(<#name#>) attribute to provide Objective-C names for properties and methods when necessary. For example, you can mark a property called enabled to have a getter named isEnabled in Objective-C like this:
>
> SWIFT
>
> `var enabled: Bool {
>       @objc(isEnabled) get {
>       /* ... */
>       }
>   }`

## Named Objective-C Getter Property in Swift

```
var _enabled:Bool = false
var enabled:Bool {
    @objc(isEnabled) get {
        return self._enabled
    }
    set(newValue){
        _enabled = newValue
    }
}
```

## `readonly` Objective-C Property in Swift

**Either**

```
var _exists:Bool = false
private(set) var exists:Bool {
    get{
        return self._exists
    }
    set(newValue){
        self._exists = newValue
    }
}
```

**or**

```
var _exists:Bool = false
var exists:Bool {
    get{
        return self._exists
    }
}
```

and access `self._exists` directly since there is no setter.